# Unable to run the wordpress and laravel side by side on nginx according to specified url structure

Tags: wordpress, nginx, laravel-5

I have to run wordpress and laravel side by side on the nginx server. The url structure required is **example.com** (to show the wordpress content) and **example.com/testapp** (for the laravel application). The config I am using for nginx currently, is doing just opposite.

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/default/public;
    #root /home/forge/apen;




    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Its handling all the routes starting with **example.com** except for **example.com/testapp** through laravel. **example.com/testapp** is serving the wordpress content. Wordpress folder is saved inside public folder of laravel.

I installed the wordpress seprately and and tried to create a separate server names in /etc/nginx/sites-available one for **example.com** and another for **example.com/testapp**. After this **example.com** is showing the wordpress content but **example.com/testapp** is not loading laravel content.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your vHost and try again! Hope it will work!

```
 location /testapp/ {
        # Do nothing. nginx will serve files as usual.
    }
```

Let me know if it works!
It will ignore the test app Directory and Wordpress will be able to take control of the Routes Having the /testapp/ Theoretically!

Comment: Adarsh thanks for your response. It did not worked out.